# Dns email records godaddy and AWS route53

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I've decided to move my dns records to AWS Route53, but I have a problem with email server. 
So, godaddy offers an cpanel email serves that is good for me and I want to stay with it. The problem is that I cannot send email to *@mydomain.com. I've read a bit about it, find the solution:

```
Name    Type     Value
         MX      0  smtp.secureserver.net. 
                 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
```

But the problem is that email don't get to the email servers. 
I've sent an email from my gmail account and got an error:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>  name@mydomain.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   mydomain.co by smtp.secureserver.net. [68.178.213.203].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 550 5.1.1
>    Recipient not found. 
>   http://x.co/irbounce
>   Emails from godaddy cpanel email get to my gmail account without any problems.

I think that I've missed something, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Verify e-mail works when you switch back to Godaddy's DNS servers.
2. Find out the MX records for your domain name as they are with Godaddy.
3. Use the AWS Route53 DNS servers for your domain and set up the MX records for your domain name the same as they were with Godaddy.
4. Check the MX records and verify e-mail works. If it doesn't work it seems Godaddy removes your domain from their mail servers and you will have to contact Godaddy support for a solution.